# What is the relation ship between im(A) and im(AB)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Consider an $ n \times p$ matrix $A$ and a $p \times m $ matrix $B$. What is the relation ship between $\operatorname{im}(A)$ and $\operatorname{im}(AB)$?

If we know the $\operatorname{im}(A)$ we know the columns of $A$ in rref. (I understand that this is true because the image of a linear transformation is the span of the column vectors of $A$). Now if we want to find $\operatorname{im}(AB)$ we know that we can get back to A by applying the opposite row operations of $B$ (what does this mean.. multiply by the inverse of $B$?) As a result we know that $\operatorname{im}(AB)$ will necessarily be contained in $\operatorname{im}(A)$ (this is still not clear to me, what does this mean exactly?)

Answer (score 2):

I don't find what you copied particularly illuminating, so I'll try and provide a different perspective.

If $A$ is given by an $n \times p$ matrix, it represents a function from $\Bbb R^p$ to $\Bbb R^n$. Likewise, $B$ represents a function from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^p$.

The matrix $AB$ means that we'll do $B$ first, then $A$; we'll get a function from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$ as the composition

$$AB: \Bbb R^m \overset{B}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb R^p \overset{A}{\longrightarrow} \Bbb R^n.$$

Now, the image of $B$ is certainly a subset of $\Bbb R^p$, and quite possibly smaller; we have $\operatorname{im}(B) \subseteq \Bbb R^p$, so that the image of $B$ is at most as big as the domain, $\Bbb R^p$, of $A$.

So in the composition $AB$, by the time we're performing $A$, only vectors in $\operatorname{im}(B)$ could have "gotten through" to be fed into $A$: at best, we're feeding a set of vectors as large as $\Bbb R^p$ (but quite possibly smaller), the original domain of $A$, into $A$.

If the same function, $A$, is being performed at the end, but possibly restricted to a smaller domain (that is, $\operatorname{im}(B) \subseteq \Bbb R^p$), how could we possibly get *more* out?